# New DLL loading prohibitively slow for ASP.NET sites run on IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8, publishing

IIS 8.5 freezes for hours when starting a new site (i.e. from a new folder) or when restarting a site after some DLLs were updated.

Loading an empty (auto-created by VS) site takes about an hour, and loading my project takes a night. After load, the performance is fine, just as it is for sites already online.

Deleting all DLLs makes the sites error-out fast, but if there is any DLL in '/bin', it all freezes.

This happens only on our production server - everything's fine on other IIS servers and at localhost. We've tried rebooting twice, and it hasn't helped.

The logs are unhelpful. The applications don't even get a chance to run (i.e. even an exception in Global.asax.cs doesn't fire), it's a loading problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Turned out that it was anti-virus that was causing this. The solution was to add the temporary .NET folder to the list of AV exceptions. The vanilla folder is "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" (modify per 32/64 bit and framework version).